# gcloud auth print-identity-token returning token with wrong audiences

Tags: google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I am using google cloud auth for signing my requests for a firebase based project. Until yesterday it worked seamlessly, after using the `gcloud auth print-identity-token` I have received a token for the selected project and account. Yesterday after a restart this functionality stopped working. I still receive a token and the gcloud seems to be configured well(re-initialised it, and tried to completely uninstall/install it), but the returned token has different `aud` field. Therefore my firebase functions consider my requests as unauthenticated. let me paste the error message below:

```
Failed to validate auth token. FirebaseAuthError: Firebase ID token has incorrect "aud" (audience) claim. Expected "xyzmyproject" but got "32512345659.apps.googleusercontent.com". Make sure the ID token comes from the same Firebase project as the service account used to authenticate this SDK
```

I have checked the identity token via [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) and the `aud` is set to the wrong `32512345659.apps.googleusercontent.com` value as the error message describes it.
Furthermore while was investigating I found out that the `gcloud auth login` command redirects me to the url the `client_id` is specified as `32512345659.apps.googleusercontent.com`.

Comment: Double check the CLI configuration using commands like a) `gcloud auth list` b) `gcloud config get project`

Comment: @JohnHanley both commands returns the correct value my active account is displayed correctly and the project is also displayed correctly so got there the value of `xyzmyproject` not the `32512345659.apps.googleusercontent.com`

Comment: What is the Project Number for xyzmyproject?

Comment: have checked it as well, but nope the project number differs

Comment: Your comments are too cryptic and I am not sure what the configuration is. Can you edit your question with those details?

Comment: I had to open a new terminal window after switching accounts for it to work